# Laravel Echo/Pusher/Vue - /broadcasting/auth returns empty HTML response

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7, pusher, laravel-echo

I had managed to get a laravel/echo/pusher chat application working in my local machine. However once I uploaded to the server the authorization end-point seems failed. I tried a whole bunch of things that just made everything worse.

In my local machine I had (`app.js`):

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
authEndpoint : 'https://localhost/**********/*******/public/broadcasting/auth',
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: '*****************',
cluster: '**',
forceTLS: true,});
```

which successfully connected to pusher and broadcast events. Chat was working fine.

After uploading to the server I changed this to:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
authEndpoint : '/broadcasting/auth',
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: '**************',
cluster: 'eu',
forceTLS: true,});
```

Which, I checked, redirects to `https://example.com/broadcasting/auth`. Now this url initially returned `404`. At some point I tried to use again: `https://localhost/***/.../broadcasting/auth`, which in turn failed as cross origin request.

After playing quite a lot with configuration files, composer and npm somehow the same url returns no specific response anymore.
This is the request:

```
GET /broadcasting/auth HTTP/1.1
Host: domain_name
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=token_value activebabies_session=session_token
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2020 16:26:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=token_value; expires=Wed, 23-Sep-2020 18:26:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: activebabies_session=session_value; expires=Wed, 23-Sep-2020 18:26:01 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

There are no errors in the console. At some point there were connections to pusher, just no events broadcast. Currently there are not even connections to pusher.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I would be happy to post any additional info that may be required (app.js , .env file, broadcasting.php) but the configuration has to be correct since it worked locally...

Comment: Have you uncommented App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class, in config/app.php?

Comment: The .env file is not uploaded to the server automatically via git/githab. I re-wrote the pusher key, secret myself...there was a spelling mistake. I doubt this can be of help to anyone.

Comment: In my case, I've forgotten to change the `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` in my environment.